# how to save downloaded files in cache android

Tags: android

Hi i'm streaming video from a website in my android application. I have a history option showing the last seen videos. I wonder if i can use cache so that when the user enters the history the video is played faster (not downloaded again). When you use cache in Android does that mean that the whole video is downloaded and saved somewhere? or some data is saved somwhere(not the whole video).

Some help will be appreciated!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

It should help you.

```
    URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();   
    cn.connect();   
    InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();

    File downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "downloadingMedia.dat");

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);   
    byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
    do {
        int numread = stream.read(buf);   
        if (numread <= 0) break;   
        out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        // ... 
    } while (...);
```

Comment: so this means that the whole file will be downloaded to the cache directory? Sorry, i don't know how cache works...

Comment: @madcoderz: the whole file or just a part of it, it is up to you to decide. A cache is place to store data so that future access to it is faster. I think this is what you need.

Comment: But getCacheDir() returns a `File` and not a `String`.

Comment: @PeterAjtai: the API might have changed, so you can omit the next line (File downloadingMediaFile...)

Comment: "context.getCacheDir();" this line is not working for me. context only has constants, and no method "getCacheDir".

Comment: As per my comment above; change context.getCacheDir(); to this.getCacheDir();.

Comment: Tutorial is not longer available. There are only ads.

Comment: what should be the condition in do while?

Comment: @gulbrandr can you give some explanation to your code it may help to get things clearly thanks..