# Load images in ImageView in ListView before they appear on screen

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

I am developing an app similar to what 9gag is doing. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninegag.android.app&hl=en

I have already implemented most of it but when I run the app the images that get loaded from the internet are not loaded in the ImageView until it comes on screen. I know that this is how ListView works with recycling but it doesnt seem smooth since i have to wait for each list item to load its image every time its shown on screen.

What do you suggest I could do to improve this issue?

My CustomAdapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ResultsListener{
Context context;
Holder holder;
int postItemsLength=0;
ArrayList<PostItem> postItems;
PlaceholderFragment activity;

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(PlaceholderFragment activity, ArrayList<PostItem> postItems) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity=activity;
    this.context=activity.getContext();
    this.postItems = postItems;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Log.d("FOUND","entered constructor");


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return postItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onResultsSucceeded(Bitmap image, int position) {
    holder.img.setImageBitmap(image);
    CustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    TextView imgName;
    ImageView img;
    WebView wView;
    TextView likes;
    TextView comments;
    TextView op;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FrameLayout webViewLayout;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Holder holder;
    Log.d("FOUND","entered GetView");
    // Check if the item's view is recycled
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        Log.d("FOUND","convertView is not null");
        // The item's view doesn't exist
        // Create the item's view
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        holder = new Holder(); // Create the holder

        holder.tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        holder.img=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.likes=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likeNumTextView);
        holder.comments=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentNumTextView);
        holder.imgName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageNameTextView);
        holder.op=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opTextView);
        holder.webViewLayout = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.webViewLayout);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // Store the holder with the view.
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        // The item's view already exist
        // Retrieve the older
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        Log.d("FOUND","alreay exists");
    }

    holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_img);
    holder.tv.setText(postItems.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.imgName.setText(postItems.get(position).getImageName());
    holder.op.setText(postItems.get(position).getUploader());
    holder.likes.setText(postItems.get(position).getLikeNum()+"");
    holder.comments.setText(postItems.get(position).getCommentNum()+"");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getDpWidth(), adjustHeight(postItems.get(position).getWidth(), postItems.get(position).getHeight()));
    holder.webViewLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);


    DownloadImageTask dTask = new DownloadImageTask(holder.img);
    dTask.setOnResultsListener(CustomAdapter.this);
    dTask.execute("http://torifi.net/images/" + postItems.get(position).getImageName());

    Log.d("FOUND","entered");
    //holder.likes.setText(likeNum.get(position));
     //    holder.comments.setText(commentNum.get(position));

    /*
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO impl

        }
    });
*/
    return convertView;
}

public int getDpWidth()
{
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(displayMetrics.widthPixels);// / displayMetrics.density);
}

public int adjustHeight (float imageWidth, float imageHeight)
{
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;// / displayMetrics.density;
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;// / displayMetrics.density;

    return Math.round((imageHeight/imageWidth)*dpWidth);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load your images, which cache your images until their uri changes, and gives very fast and smooth loading experience.

you can load images as simple as following example.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load("image url").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Will try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to seperate download and view creation.

You know the data to display in your *ListView*, so download the images onto the device (for example into the apps cache-dir like shown in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4691203/3994580)).
You don't have to eagerly download the images of all the *ListView*s entries. Just keep track of the users scrolling status and start downloading the next few images.

When initializing the ImageView set the Image-Source to your local file like shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065952/3994580).

Comment: Hi. i dont think dowbloading all the images would be very efficient since my listview is "infinite". Maybe i can download like 10 of them each time save them at the cache and load them from there. Because i dont think i can load 500+ images in the cache.